# HTML code is not work on Chrome and server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, browser

I have a simple HTML page which is gets pictures from the JSON file by using `ResponsiveSlides.js` it is work in Firefox but it is not shows empty page in other browser and also when I run it  from the server it is just shows the picture separately without animation? What should I do to run my HTML in all browsers and server?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ResponsiveSlides.js/1.55/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div>
<ul id="exampleSlider">
</ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('slides.json', function(data) {
    $("h2").html(data[0].title);
        $.each(data, function (i, f) {
            if(i>0){
                $("#exampleSlider").append("<li><a><img src=" + f.content + "></img></a><p>"+f.title+"</p></li>");
                $("a").attr("href", "#");
            }
        });
   });

    $(function () {
      $("#exampleSlider").responsiveSlides({
        auto: true,
        pause: true,
        speed: 1200,
        timeout: 3000
      });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the `responsiveSlides` **after** you have inserted your images in the page (*after the AJAX is complete*).

```js
$(function() {

  $.getJSON('slides.json', function(data) {

    $("h2").html(data[0].title);

    $.each(data, function(i, f) {
      if (i > 0) {
        $("#exampleSlider").append("<li><a><img src=" + f.content + "></img></a><p>" + f.title + "</p></li>");
        $("a").attr("href", "#");
      }
    });

    $("#exampleSlider").responsiveSlides({
      auto: true,
      pause: true,
      speed: 1200,
      timeout: 3000
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: thanks, now works on server, but still don't work on other browser like chrome or opera this is the error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/saeed/Desktop/final/bs-binary-admin/assets/json/slides.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: @alex yes, ajax requests do not work in chrome on the `file://` protocol (*locally*). See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47416